# Azure AD integration with SharePoint 2013 on premise server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, azure-ad, sso

I am trying to integrate Azure AD with local SharePoint 2013 on premise server. I have followed steps given in below URL.

[Tutorial: Azure Active Directory integration with SharePoint on-premises](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial)

After completing all steps when I visit my local SharePoint site URL it redirects me on login.microsoftonline.com but gives shown error:

[image]

Error text:

> Sign in
>
> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS750054: SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query
>   string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding.

Please let me know if any other steps needs to be followed along with this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD wasn’t able to identify the SAML request within the URL parameters in the HTTP request.

The application needs to send the SAML request encoded into the location header using HTTP redirect binding.

For more information about how to implement it, read the section HTTP Redirect Binding in the https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf (page 15)

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same issue, we changed our ProviderUri on the SharePoint to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/wsfed
```

We also had to add the SSO certificate into the trusted root of the app and front end server.